# TCPDF library, file tcpdf_fonts.php missing after uploading

Tags: server, tcpdf, uploading

When i upload TCPDF library files to live server, the file tcpdf_fonts.php from tcpdf/include folder dissapears .. any idea of why ?

Answer (score 0):

The file tcpdf_fonts.php has been blaklisted by the hosting company.

Requesting for include it in a whitelist (solved).